# web3.js to use with web development

Tags: web3js, solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

I want to use web3.js together with my web page but the require function is not working for me. I have tried using browserify , importing instead of declaring as const but none worked, one problem solution lead to another problem. I tried to bundle these but web3 module has also some js inside which uses import statement so I am getting error to bundle them as well.
[issue while using web3js with require](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK6Wp.png)

[simple js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sah6h.png)

[issue while using web3js with import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxVoQ.png)

[simple js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eowxz.png)

Comment: Please boil down your problem to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share it as code, not pictures.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `import` you wrote is wrong. Here are a few examples:

```js
import {
  Keypair,
  AccountMeta,
  Connection,
  PublicKey,
  Transaction,
  TransactionInstruction,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
```

Or

```js
import web3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
```